# Free IP address management software

Tags: networking, ip

We are choosing a system for managing our IP address space. So we are looking for a special free software like IPPlan.
So what we have nowadays:

- [Ipplan](http://iptrack.sourceforge.net/) (Beta IPv6 support)
- [SolarWinds IP address tracker](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/ip_address_tracker/) (IPv6 support unknown )
- IP module of [The NOC Project](http://trac.nocproject.org/trac/) (BTW, take a look of it, seems to be very promising project) (IPv6 support unknown )
- [phpIP](http://www.phpip.net/) (Does not support IPv6)
- IP management from [RackTables](http://racktables.org) (Does not support IPv6)

Do you know about any other special software, like written above?

But:

- No Wiki
- No DNS
- No DHCP
- No spreadsheet

Software should provide:

- Clear view of available addresses
- Detail listing of all addresses by subnets/search pattern/owners/additional info
- It must support adding additional info like owner of IP, domain-name, contacts, etc
- Multi user support
- Easy interface
- Software has to be specially written
  for address management.
- Scalability
- Any OS: win, lin, sol, web

Comment: So you don't want DHCP or DNS management?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "managing" your IP address space? What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: As you are specifically asking for software, what operating system(s) does it need to run on?

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, dns|dhcp management covers a small part of management, I cant store additional info
@John Gardeniers: Ok, i have added some more info to question.

Comment: For the record, a year after this was originally posted, it looks like the beta version 6.00-BETA1 of IPplan does indeed support ipv6.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using ipplan in production where I work and I'm quite happy with it. However do note that it doesn't support ipv6 and will require a complete rewrite for it to do so.

I have yet to find an ip address management project that will handle ipv6 well. That NOC project looks promising though.

Answer (score 2):

I tried [PHP-IP](http://www.phpip.net/console.php), it's a webapp with a MySQL backend. But its currently v4-only. Another tool I use is [RackTables](http://racktables.org/). It's not just an IPAM tool, rather a rack manager, where your can document your devices, store config details and so on.

Comment: Nice two managers, I will add them to topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have found two more good looking options.

- [GestióIP](http://www.gestioip.net/)
- [NetDoT](https://netdot.uoregon.edu/trac/)

GestióIP looks like the custom software my group uses but so much better.  If it works anything like the video and screenshots show, it looks to be the best option I've seen.

I'm trying to get NetDoT to work as I've fallen into dependency hell trying to get it to work on Ubuntu.

I'll try to come back with reviews in a few weeks, but I wanted everyone to see these options.

Answer (score 1):

nmap and a spreadsheet. Keep your tools simple.

Comment: Does not scale and multiuser write access to a spreadsheet is painfully hard or impossible depending on the software.

Comment: Sorry missed the multi user bullet. I agree.
@TiFFolk, thank you for the elucidating comment.

Comment: I just wanted to point out, that spreadsheet is EVIL =)

Comment: Yeah - we have spreadsheets too.  Terrible and leads to mistakes eventually.  You need a database with constraints.

Comment: Multiuser write access? Google Docs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest http://opennetadmin.com.  I think it supports most of what you want.  It is not a requirement to manage DNS or DHCP though it is an option.

It does however require at least one "name" to be put in for each host that is managed.

It supports a nice clean AJAX web front end and a CLI interface as well.  Its PHP/mysql based so it should run on most unix OSes (I know windows has not been tested yet).  The web GUI that you use can be ran from just about any web browser.

IPV6 is on the list of todos but is not available yet.

You can add "custom attributes" to hosts and subnets.

It supports plugins as well so other features can be added.  It supports various levels integration with Puppet, nagios etc.  It comes with an nmap based reporting and auditing tool to ensure the data in the database is as accurate as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for GestioIP. I work for a company that owns a full class B subnet, try keeping track of that on a spreadsheet!

Comment: "Class B" subnets don't exist. Do you mean a /16 CIDR netblock?

Comment: Gee,funny comment. Arh arh arh.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on a quick look, I've downloaded SolarWinds' free product and will give that a try.

Like the guy in their demo video, I have fond memories of my first address range and we managed that for years with an increasingly complicated spreadsheet.  (First it had DECnet and IP addresses, then it dropped the DECnet stuff and added routable and non-routable, DMZ, specialized sub-nets, static assignments...)

Answer (score 0):

IPAM Module of the NOC Project has full IPv6 support with proper DNS integration. There are nice [Screencasts](http://redmine.nocproject.org/wiki/noc/Screencasts) on the project's site with this module in action.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [phpIPAM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpipam/). It has nice UI, multiuser, etc. but no IPv6 at the moment and no auto scaning.

I tried GestioIP but I didn't like. Still searching for the right one. For now I'm using phpIPAM.